# Can't shutdown mandriva 2010.2

Tags: kernel, shutdown, mandriva

I can't seem to shutdown my machine from mandriva,I have to restart to shut it down from GRUB

it says "System Halted" and just freezes there

I'm using the x86_64 GNOME version

I've already asked on mandriva forums and they couldn't determine the cause of this problem

P.S. I'm using the 2.6.36.2-desktop-2mnb kernel

Comment: This is usually due to an incompatibility with your firmware (motherboard, BIOS, ACPI, …). What motherboard (or computer model) do you have? Have you set up anything related to ACPI?

Comment: my motherboard is Gigabyte GA-MA790GP-UD4H and I did disable ACPI,and didn't solve the problem,note that I didn't have this problem with 2010.1

Comment: Could you please provide the link to that forum thread, so that we know what already was tried?

Comment: there you go http://goo.gl/DWDHR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the cause of the problem was ACPI,it was switched off

turning it back on solved the problem :)

just in case somebody has a similar issue